# Alternative of user pool of cognito [AWS] in google identity platform [GCP]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-cognito, google-identity-toolkit, google-cloud-identity

AWS Cognito has a concept of userpool and each pool has its app clients. We are trying to implement the same in GCP and found that Google Identity platform is an alternative to cognito. But I am not able to find any such option for user pools in GCP Identity platform. Please advice

Comment: Do you want to create groups? https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/groups

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Can we integrate this with Google Identity platform? The groups I am looking for identity platform users

Comment: Hmm correct, you can create tenant, but not groups. Groups are for Google Accounts

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) as an equivalent of Amazon Cognito. In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/mobile#languages_and_platforms), you will find a table with a comparison  between Amazon Cognito and Firebase Authentication.